# Why does this python script crash my IDE?

Tags: python, python-idle

This script is crashing my Python IDE:

```
def flashCard(word,definition):
    print word + "\n" + definition
    return word + definition

def buildCard():
    word = input("Front?")
    definition = input("Back?")
    flashCard(word,definition)



buildCard()
```

I am using IDLE for Mac on OSX 10.7.4

Comment: By "crashing", do you mean "raises a NameError" or "raises a SyntaxError"?

Comment: well, it isn't why your ide is crashing, but if you're returning the `word + definition` string from `flashCard`, you should probably be doing this:  `wordAndDef = flashCard(word,definition)` in your `buildCard` method. Otherwise there's no sense in returning anything

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: @DSM I mean it literally beachballs the machine and I have to force quit out of the IDE...

Comment: @JaeGeeTee then you should test John's solution. I have tested this on windows 7 and IDLE behaves as expected (ie raises an exception for invalid input)

Comment: @JaeGeeTee I really doubt that anything in the script is what's crashing your IDE. It's possible that the file itself is corrupted and IDLE doesn't know how to handle it. For this, I'd just suggest copy-and-pasting into a new .py file and trying it again. I'm fairly sure that'll work, unless its *all* scripts that are causing the problem

Answer (score 3):

Might be because you're using input(), try replacing the calls to input() with raw_input().  (Just guessing here, but that could be it depending upon the version of Python you're running.)  In Python 2.x input is:

```
input([prompt]) 
Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not
>   syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions
>   may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide
>   elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

Comment: in python 3 input replaces raw_input. But it is probably the problem.

Comment: I replaced, and it still crashes.  You know your code is bad when your IDE blows up.

Comment: However, It did allow my code to execute correctly from the command line.  Thanks.

Comment: Compare version at top of IDLE when when it starts up with what you get at command line when you execute `python -V`.  You may be running different versions.